# Try get AccessToken in the loop. and save into variable in swift

Tags: swift

For UI testing, we are serving argument to our app that it should call API for creating new user and then get the access token for this user and start app as a logged in.
The problem is in backend, sometimes it this takes milliseconds, but sometimes more than one second till the access token is available.

I would like to rewrite the following code snippet (try? await UITests...) to include a retry loop that attempts the operation multiple times (e.g., 5 times) with a one-second delay between retries.

```swift
guard let accessToken = try? await UITestsNetwork.shared.autoLogin(email: credentials.email, password: credentials.password).async()
else {
    return
}
intializeLogin(with: accessToken)
```

In case it will help, here is the header of the autoLogin function:

```swift
autoLogin(email: String, password: String) -> AnyPublisher<AccessToken, Error>
```

In ideal world I'm searching for something like this --- **THIS IS NOT A SOLUTION !!!**

```swift
guard let accessToken = for _ in 5 {
                            do {
                                token = try await UITestsNetwork.shared.autoLogin(email: credentials.email, password: credentials.password).async()
                                return token
                            catch {
                                print("Couldn't create the access token")
                                sleep(1)
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Do you want to do multiples calls, or like a sleep for n randoms seconds to simulate the latency?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would like to perform multiple calls, and once I receive a successful response from the autologin process (containing an AccessToken instead of an Error), I would like to stop making further calls.